# Derivative of matrix variable product with respect to matrix variable

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

> For $g: R^{n \times p} \to R^{n \times n}, U \mapsto UU^{T}$ what is the full derivative of $g$ respect to $U$

This questions arises when I am trying to find the derivative of $\langle C,UU^{T} \rangle$, with respect to the matrix U, where C is a constant $n \times n$ matrix and the inner product is canonical. I attempted to use the chain rule and got the above question

I have spent quite some time searching up this question, and I did find many posts that seems to be related. However, as I don't have much knowledge in differential geometry nor machine learning, I quickly become overwhelmed to the notation. I am doing this problem with the full derivative so I expect the solution to be a $nn \times np$ matrix, but if there are other nicer notations to use, please let me know as well.

> Just out of curiosity, what can I do in general to find the derivative of $f: X \mapsto u(X)v(X)$ where $X$ is a matrix and $u(X)$ and $v(X)$ outputs a matrix

Comment: Just use the product rule. The derivative of $f$ at $X$ is the linear map $Df_X:\,Y\mapsto Du_X(Y)v(X)+u(X)Dv_X(Y)$. In particular, $Dg_U$ is the linear map $Y\mapsto YU^T+UY^T$.

Comment: So, with respect to the two standard bases of $\mathbb R^{n\times p}$ and $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, the matrix representation of $Dg_U$ is $U\otimes I_n+(I_n\otimes U)K^{(n,p)}$ or equivalently $U\otimes I_n+K^{(n,n)}(U\otimes I_n)$, where $K^{(r,s)}$ denotes the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) for $r\times s$ matrices.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you. Can you elaborate on why $Du_{U}(Y) = Y$ and $Dv_{U}(Y) = Y^T$ in this case?

Comment: You don't need this matrix-matrix gradient to calculate the derivative of your scalar function, which is
$$\large\eqalign{
\frac{\partial \left\langle C,\,UU^T \right\rangle}{\partial U}
 &= CU+C^TU \\
}$$

Comment: @greg Can you elaborate on how you got this?

Comment: @wsz_fantasy [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3919948) provides the details. Or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4645762/357854)

Comment: @wsz_fantasy I suppose that you have learnt the definition of [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative). In the case for $g$, the function $u$ is the identity map and $v$ is the transposition map. Both mappings are linear. Since the derivative of a linear map is itself. the conclusion follows.